# Dojo date text box calendar hidden

Tags: html, date, dojo

I have a problem with mi dojo DATE, i have this code:

```
<div style="z-index:-1">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="date">Start date: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
data-dojo-id="myStartDate" 
onChange="myEndDate.constraints.min = arguments[0];" 
type="text" 
name="sdate" 
id="sdate"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Thist DIV is in a POPUP, and the POPUP is a other DIV.

But when you do click on the DOJO DATE, the calendar appear behind of the POPUP ,
How I Can to move the calender infront of the all screen, infront of the all DIVS.

Thanks

Comment: Could you create minimal example, including the dialog? For example on jsfiddle.net? Do you use dijit/Dialog?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. Can do you see the same behavior in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/57u7p6c3/1/ Which browser?